# How to loop the data[] series with php and mysql

Tags: php, mysql, sql, highcharts

Here is my table structure.
 [image]

[image]

I am using highcharts

Here is my code:

```
    $(function () {
      $('#container_journal').highcharts({

        xAxis: {
            categories: [
                 '1995', '1996', '1997', '1988'
        ]
        },
        yAxis: {
            title: {
                text: 'Citations'
            },
            plotLines: [{
                value: 0,
                width: 1,
                color: '#808080'
            }]
        },
        tooltip: {
            valueSuffix: ''
        },
        legend: {
            layout: 'vertical',
            align: 'right',
            verticalAlign: 'middle',
            borderWidth: 0
        },
        series: [{
            name: 'A + U-Architecture and Urbanism',
            data: [<?php 
            $test_q = mysql_query("SELECT jour_id, journal, citations, year FROM journ_graph WHERE jour_id = '1'");
    while($row_q = mysql_fetch_array($test_q)){
        $year_q = $row_q['year'];
        $citations_q = $row_q['citations'];
        echo $citations_q.',';
    }
        ?>]
        },{
            name: 'AACE International. Transactions of the Annual Meeting',
            data: [
                   <?php 
            $test_q = mysql_query("SELECT jour_id, journal, citations, year FROM journ_graph  WHERE jour_id = '2'");
                         while($row_q =  mysql_fetch_array($test_q)){
                            $year_q = $row_q['year'];
                            $citations_q =  $row_q['citations'];
                            echo $citations_q.',';
                         }
       ?>]
         },{
            name: 'AACL Bioflux',
            data: [
                   <?php 
              $test_q = mysql_query("SELECT jour_id, journal, citations, year FROM journ_graph WHERE jour_id = '3'");
    while($row_q = mysql_fetch_array($test_q)){
    $year_q = $row_q['year'];
    $citations_q = $row_q['citations'];
    echo $citations_q.',';
    }
         ?>]
        }
      ?>]
      ]
    });
   });
```

Here im entering manually the id. in where clause(refer code), the graph is showing.
Look Below: [image]
SELECT jour_id, journal, citations, year FROM journ_graph WHERE jour_id = '3'
In the above statement im entering the id manually, but i need it to come from the first table, jour_id.

I tried that too but its not working.

```
   series: [
    <?php 
    $query_jour = mysql_query("SELECT jour_id, journal, citations, year FROM journ_graph");
                                                     $query_journ_count = mysql_num_rows($query_jour);
                                         while($row_journ = mysql_fetch_array($query_jour)){
                                         $jour_id = $row_journ['jour_id'];

  ?>
    {
            data: [<?php 
          $test_q = mysql_query("SELECT jour_id, journal, citations, year FROM journ_graph WHERE jour_id = '$jour_id'");
    while($row_q = mysql_fetch_array($test_q)){
        $year_q = $row_q['year'];
        $citations_q = $row_q['citations'];
        echo $citations_q.',';
    }
    ?>]
       }
  <?php
  }?>
```

I have used two while loops but eventhough its not working. Please tell me where I am going wrong. Please help.

Comment: If you need to get the related data you need to use a [JOIN](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/join.html).  `SELECT * FROM journ_graph JOIN first_table ON jour_graph.jour_id = first_table.jour_id`

Comment: Where do I need to use the join. Please help. I am new to high charts.

Comment: You need to stop using the _deprecated_ mysql_* extension, and please: don't go and string all data manually, we have `json_encode` to do just that

Comment: Ah that json_encode is making problem, please guide to use the right syntax, I am new here.

Answer (score 0):

I advice you to run one query to database, prepare array which will contain three series, then you json_encode() in PHP and get data via AJAX in javascript. It will be more clearful.

Comment: I tried that way too bro but sadly i am not getting the required output.

Comment: How your output looks like ?